# Almost sure convergence in parameters preserves convergence in distribution

Tags: limits, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ denote a sequence of real-valued random variables that converges in distribution to the standard normal distribution. In addition, each $X_n(c)$ is a function of a  real-valued parameter $c$. I.e. $X_n(c) \stackrel{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Now, assume $c$ is unkown but the sequence $c_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ converges almost sure to $c$.

What are sufficient conditions for the functions $X_n(c)$, such that $X_n(c_n) \stackrel{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ as $n\to\infty$? (As stated above, at the limit point $c$ the sequence $X_n(c)$ also converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.)

This statement cannot be true in general. But, I assume it holds if $X_n$ are continuous functions of $c$. Does it?

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT]
Here is a counterexample for $X_n:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous. (This doesn't seem to work for $X_n$ defined over all of $\mathbb{R}$, as you commented).

Let $N\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and define:
$$
X_n(c):=\begin{cases}
N, & \text{if }n>c^{-1}+1,\\
N(n-c^{-1}), & \text{if }c^{-1}\leq n\leq c^{-1}+1,\\
0, & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$

In other words, $c\mapsto X_n(c)$ is $0$ for small $n$ but normally distributed for large $n$. In between, the function linearly interpolates - hence continuity of $c\mapsto X_n(c)$. (You could even find a polynomial interpolation in between with Weierstrass, then you have a smooth counter-example).
Evidently, $X_n(n^{-1})=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which completes the counterexample.

I think these references might be helpful to find sufficient conditions:
[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) and [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).

Comment: But how do you define $X_n(c)$ for $c = 0$ which is the limit of $c_n$? Now it's undefined. If you choose $X_n(0) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then $X_n(c)$ wouldn't be continuous in $c$. If you choose $X_n(0)=0$ it violates $X_n(c)\stackrel{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$  as $n\to\infty$,

Comment: Apologies, I edited my answer. I'm not sure about the case where $X_n$ is continuous over all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It doesn't need to be continuous for all $\mathbb{R}$. However, it should be defined at the limit point $c$ as assumed above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another counterexample, perhaps more convincing.

Let $B_t$ be the standard Brownian motion.
Then, the following map is almost surely continuous:
$$
X_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\quad c\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^c}}B_{e^c}
$$
For all $c\in\mathbb{R}$, $X_n(x)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, by construction of the Brownian motion.
Moreover, define the following sequence:
$$
c_n:=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }B_1>0,\\
\ln (2),&\text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$
Trivially, this is an almost surely convergent sequence.
Note that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$
\mathbb{P}[X_n(c_n)>0]=\mathbb{P}\left[\{B_1>0\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}B_{2}>0\right\}\right]
$$
$$
=\mathbb{P}[B_1>0]+\mathbb{P}\left[\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}B_{2}>0\right\}\setminus \{B_1>0\} \right]
=\frac{1}{2}+\gamma
$$
Where $\gamma>0$.
So, $X_n(c_n)$ cannot have a normal distribution.
As $X_n(c_n)$ is identical to its limit, it does not converge to a normally distributed random variable either.

Comment: I've problems parsing your counter example. Please help me. First, I see for $X_n$ no dependence on $n$. I assume they are i.i.d., right?

Comment: Yes, here $X_n$ does not depend on $n$. So, $X_1=X_2=\dots$. Hence, they are identically distributed, but not independent. You can think of Brownian motion as the continuous version of a random walk. This doesn't really matter for the example, but it is convenient for an example which is continuous in $c$. What matters is that $B_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Secondly, how can $c_n$ converge almost surely as it depends on the random variable $B_1$ for all $n$?

Comment: It's true that $c_n$ depends on $B_1$, but that just means it is a random variable. Using the notation for random variables, for any $\omega\in\Omega$, you have $c_1(\omega)=c_2(\omega)=\dots$, since the $B_1(\omega)$ does not change with $n$. So, the sequence is constant for all $\omega\in\Omega$. Therefore, $c_n\rightarrow c_1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Yes, but $c_1$ is a random variable. So almost sure convergence to $c_1$ is not the same as alnost sure convergence to $c$. Isn't it? What would be $c$ in your case, can you tell without knowing $c_1$ (which changes due to sampling)?

Comment: Sure, the limit is a random variable. If you allow that $c_n$ is random, but require that $c$ is fixed, please state this in your question more clearly.

Comment: How could you interpret "a real-valued parameter $c$" differently? Anyway, the discussion with you helped me, in particular the link to the "Continuous mapping theorem" so I upvoted your other answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120594/discussion-between-idontgetit-and-its-me).